# Can NSRange variable contain multiple ranges?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

Is it possible that NSRange variable contains multiple ranges? Something like:

```
 var multipleRanges: NSRange = [NSMakeRange(0, 2), NSMakeRange(10, 1), ...]
```

Or maybe there is another varaible type for multiple ranges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or maybe there is another varaible type for multiple ranges?

Yes, `NS(Mutable)IndexSet` stores a collection of (unique) unsigned integers as a sequence of ranges.

Example: Create mutable index set and add two ranges and a single index:

```
let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
indexSet.addIndexesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 2))
indexSet.addIndexesInRange(NSMakeRange(10, 3))
indexSet.addIndex(5)
println(indexSet)
// <NSMutableIndexSet: 0x10050a510>[number of indexes: 6 (in 3 ranges), indexes: (0-1 5 10-12)]
```

Enumerate all indexes:

```
indexSet.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { (index, stop) -> Void in
    println(index)
}
// Output: 0 1 5 10 11 12
```

Enumerate all ranges:

```
indexSet.enumerateRangesUsingBlock { (range, stop) -> Void in
    println(range)
}
// Output: (0,2) (5,1) (10,3)
```

Test membership:

```
if indexSet.containsIndex(11) {
    // ...
}
```

But note that `NSIndexSet` represents a *set*, i.e. there are no duplicate elements,
and the order of elements does not matter. This may or may not
be useful depending on your needs. Example:

```
let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
indexSet.addIndexesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 4))
indexSet.addIndexesInRange(NSMakeRange(2, 4))
indexSet.enumerateRangesUsingBlock { (range, stop) -> Void in
    println(range)
}
// Output: (0,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

A single `NSRange` variable can hold a single range. If you need to store several ranges, make an array:

```
var multipleRanges: [NSRange] = [NSMakeRange(0, 2), NSMakeRange(10, 1)]
//                  ^       ^
//                  |       |
// This tells Swift that you are declaring an array, and that array elements
// are of NSRange type.
```

You could also omit the type, and let the compiler infer it for you:

```
// This is the same declaration as above, but now the type of array element
// is specified implicitly through the type of initializer elements:
var multipleRanges = [NSMakeRange(0, 2), NSMakeRange(10, 1)]
```

Comment: You could also omit the type annotation and let the compiler infer the type: `var multipleRanges = [NSMakeRange(0, 2), NSMakeRange(10, 1)]`.